# Convert unknown object to list of custom class

Tags: c#, json, collections, converters

I don't know if it possible, but I try...:

I pass from javascript to c# any object.
For exapmle:

```
{
    name:'ser',
    age:8
}
```

At server-side, I have custom class look like:

```
public class generaly
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
    public bool? isKey { get; set; }
}
```

I need to convert my object, so after convert I want to have List of generaly objects:

```
    [
       {FieldName:"name", FieldValue:"ser", isKey:null},
       {FieldName:"age", FieldValue:"8", isKey:null}
    ];
```

I tried using dynamic type, expando object, dictionary... but it didn't help me becouse I need the finall result to be list of my class (generaly).

I there any solution to this situation?

Comment: [Naming conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618316/naming-convention-in-c-sharp) are  useful: it increases readability and also helps to  prevent bugs. It's also easier for others to understand your code.

Comment: This wont be possible unless you write your own implementation to convert the javascript object into a c# object

Comment: Please refer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496951/convert-javascript-object-into-c-sharp-object

is this what you are looking for?  also refer , if you can build this kind of DLL for your project http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907775/how-to-map-json-response-to-custom-class-object

Comment: Tim Schmelter - Can you be specific? I cannot understand how this link help me. Desmukh and Tim - the related question are not good for me.

Comment: What Tim and Deshmukh are saying is that you need to change your class  or change the json object so that you can deserialize the object into c#. Try something like `string test = "{name:'ser', age:'9'}";
            JObject obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(test);
            List<MyClass> cls = new List<MyClass>();
            foreach (var o in obj)
            {
                cls.Add(new MyClass() { FieldName=o.Key, FieldValue = o.Value.ToString() });
            }`

Comment: Thanks, this way I know, but I thougth may be there is sorter way... Thank you all for your answers